# How to set NPM command line flags with `node2nix`?

Tags: npm, nix

Trying to install Puppeteer, but it keeps failing for some `storage.googleapis.com` security limitations as the install process is trying to download the latest Chromium binary from there. After looking at many related GitHub issues ([1](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1597),[2](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2173),[3](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3107)), the only thing that works is setting `npm`'s [`--unsafe-perm=true`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm) command line flag when using a non-Nix-installed `npm`.

I couldn't find anything in the [main `node2nix` README](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix) and in the `node2nix --help` output on how to specify additional [NPM command line flags](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config). (Did I overlook something?)

Found the [`buildNodePackage` lambda](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix/blob/c876bb8f8749d53ef759de809ce2aa68a8cce20e/nix/node-env.nix#L366) below in the [`node2nix` source](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix) with an `npmFlags` argument defaulting to an empty string:

```
  # Builds and composes an NPM package including all its dependencies
  buildNodePackage =
    { name
    , packageName
    , version
    , dependencies ? []
    , buildInputs ? []
    , production ? true
    , npmFlags ? ""
    , dontNpmInstall ? false
    , bypassCache ? false
    , reconstructLock ? false
    , preRebuild ? ""
    , dontStrip ? true
    , unpackPhase ? "true"
    , buildPhase ? "true"
    , ... }@args:
```

If this `npmFlags` needs to be overridden, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final Nix expression depends on the `node2nix` use case ([1](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix#deploying-a-nodejs-development-project) and [2](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix#deploying-a-collection-of-npm-packages-from-the-npm-registry)), but the good thing is that the same set of Nix expressions need to be overridden:

`node2nix` will generate three files in either case:

1. **`node-env.nix`**
   Defines `buildNodeSourceDist`, `buildNodePackage`, and `buildNodeShell` overridable Nix expressions. The latter two both have both have an `npmFlags` attribute in their argument.
2. **`node-packages.nix`**
   Defines a lambda enumerating all dependencies, and returns an attribute set.

- [Use case 1](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix#deploying-a-nodejs-development-project)'s attribute set contains
  `tarball` (to make source archive via `buildNodeSourceDist`)
  `package` (to build the project via `buildNodePackage`), and
  `shell` (to set up a dev environment for the the project via `buildNodeShell`)
- The attribute set returned in [use case 2](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix#deploying-a-collection-of-npm-packages-from-the-npm-registry) consists of the name of the packages built via `buildNodePackage`, from the input list (usually located in `node-packages.json`).

3. **`default.nix`**
   Imports `node-packages.nix`, and calls the imported lambda, returning either of the two attribute sets above.

To specify flags, one can override the input attribute set, using the [example](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix#adding-unspecified-dependencies) mentioned in the `node2nix` README:

```
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {
    inherit system;
}, system ? builtins.currentSystem}:

let
  nodePackages = import ./default.nix {
    inherit pkgs system;
  };
in
nodePackages // {
  
  # use case 1
  # ==========
  # shell   = nodePackages.shell.override {
  # package = nodePackages.package.override {

  # use case 2
  # ==========
  aPackageName = nodePackages.aPackageName.override {
    npmFlags = "--unsafe-perm=true";
  };
}
```